# What material is used for the floor panels in the main cabin for Boeing 747-400?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history, boeing-747, aircraft-structures

Just conducting some research into materials used in construction for Boeing 747-400 and Douglas DC-3.

I just found out that in a DC-3 the floor panels in the main cabin and companionway are of plywood.

As such, I tried to find the information with regards to Boeing 747-400, but was unsuccessful.

I was hoping someone could provide me with information with regards to the material of the floor panels in the main cabin and companionway of Boeing 747-400.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This illustration is earlier than a -400. Later ones might differ. There are two types: the normal one has aluminum skins bonded to a PVC core, for galleys/hold it is titanium skin bonded to a PVC core with greater strength/corrosion resistance.

[image]

[747 cutaway view](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1968/1968-1%20-%200110.PDF)

---

Later a honeycomb sandwich was used, apparently two cross plied glass-epoxy prepreg skins bonded to phenolic coated nomex honeycomb core using an epoxy film adjesive. From:

> Handbook of Adhesives and Sealants: volume 1, 2005

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I wonder if the honeycomb structure was introduced into 747-400.

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak specifically of the 747, but most floors in airliners these days are carbon fibre sandwich with a nomex honeycomb core.  Older ones may be fibreglass/nomex.